# What is the difference between syllable-timing and stress-timing?

Tags: phonology, linguistic-typology, stress, syllable-timing, rhythm

From what I've heard, syllable-timed languages have syllables of equal length throughout each breath-group (i.e. bit of spoken discourse said in one breath), and stress-timed languages have breath-groups of equal length.   By this account, the former entails variation in the length of each breath-group and the latter entails variation in syllable length.

However, I could have botched these definitions.  Also, I've heard rumors that the timing scheme in a given language can change with rate of speech.  I've also heard a rumor that this distinction isn't quite valid.

Therefore I'm asking for a brief and authoritative statement about the difference between stress-timing and syllable timing, and whether this distinction is considered valid by linguists.

Comment: The only article I can seem to find a full copy of is [*On the distinction between 'stress-timed' and 'syllable-timed' languages*](http://www.personal.reading.ac.uk/~llsroach/phon2/frp.pdf) by Peter Roach. However the preamble to that paper states it is out-of-date. What that means with respect to the definitions it puts forward, I don't know.

Comment: There are also mora-timed languages. Some examples are discussed [here](http://elanguage.net/journals/bls/article/download/2933/2868).

Comment: "stress-timed languages have breath-groups of equal length". Are you sure it's not stress-groups of equal length?

Comment: Actually, I'm not sure. What is a stress group?

Comment: @JamesGrossmann, I'm not sure if that's a real word. AFAIK stressed-timed languages have roughly equidistant stressed syllables. I.e. when there's a lot of unstressed syllables between two stressed ones, you tend to pronounce them quicker.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See the figure. Line 1 is stress timed (secondary stress ignored) and line 2 is syllable timed. IIRC, the time between each dot is the same.

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately Stackoverflow doesn't accept SVG, then the figure would be editable.